# Option dropdown list with onclick event not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to build out a website for mobile devices and I can't seem to get an onclick to work when it is added to the option item. I have read some posts and it looks like an onclick won't work in the option list on a mobile device but I can't seem to get onchange to work either which a few people have suggested. I've added everything I have done to a jsfiddle page below where the js and html all work but am stuck as to how to get this work on a mobile device. I'm a bit of a beginner with JS so am hoping I'm not completely missing very obvious or already explained elsewhere. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwieback99/5nt56/4/

HTML:
`<select class="select">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option onclick="showhideNarrow('one');">one</option>
    <option onclick="showhideNarrow('two');">two</option>
    <option onclick="showhideNarrow('three');">three</option>
    </select>
    <div class="visibleNarrow" id="one">number 1</div>
    <div class="visibleNarrow" id="two">number 2</div>
    <div class="visibleNarrow" id="three">number 3</div>`

JS
`function showhideNarrow(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("visibleNarrow");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    divid.style.display = "block";
    }
    return false;
    }`

CSS
`.visibleNarrow {
    padding-left:20px;
    ;
    }
    .select {
    max-width:440px;
    min-width:300px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#a0a0a0;
    font-size:18pt;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you need to code such things

I am surprised onclick on an option would work anywhere

I add the onchange inline but it really should be assigned onload of the page

```
<select class="select" onchange="showhideNarrow(this)">
```

using

```
function showhideNarrow(sel) {
  var id=["","one","two","three"][sel.selectedIndex];
  var divid = document.getElementById(id);
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("visibleNarrow");
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  if (divid) divid.style.display = "block";
}
```

Actually getElementsByClassName is less supported than getElementById so you can do

```
var divIds = ["","one","two","three"];
function showhideNarrow(sel) {
  var id=divIds[sel.selectedIndex];
  for (var i = 1; i < divIds.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsById(divIds[i]).style.display = id==divIds[i]?"block":"none";
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. Thank you so very much for your time on this, I really appreciate it.